# How can OpenVINO deal with CT segmentation

Tags: python, openvino

I try to use [COVID-19 CT segmentation dataset](http://medicalsegmentation.com/covid19/) to do the CT slices segmentation with NCS2.

I reference [this GitHub](https://github.com/NaveenPaluru/Segmentation-COVID-19) and use its pth file to convert to ONNX.

And I use `python mo_onnx.py --input_model model.onnx --input_shape [1,1,512,512] --data_type FP16` to generate IR files.

My expected inference result is as shown in the below image.

[image]

I have tried *segmentation_demo.py* in openvino_2021.4.689 version but the error message shows as the following.

```
[ INFO ] Initializing Inference Engine...
[ INFO ] Loading network...
[ INFO ] Reading network from IR...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\deployment_tools\inference_engine\demos\segmentation_demo\python\segmentation_demo.py", line 270, in <module>
    sys.exit(main() or 0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\deployment_tools\inference_engine\demos\segmentation_demo\python\segmentation_demo.py", line 176, in main
    model, visualizer = get_model(ie, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\deployment_tools\inference_engine\demos\segmentation_demo\python\segmentation_demo.py", line 160, in get_model
    return SegmentationModel(ie, args.model), SegmentationVisualizer(args.colors)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\common\python\models\segmentation.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.input_blob_name = self.prepare_inputs()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\demos\common\python\models\segmentation.py", line 43, in prepare_inputs
    raise RuntimeError("3-channel 4-dimensional model's input is expected")
RuntimeError: 3-channel 4-dimensional model's input is expected
```

Then, I also try to run *classification_sample_async.py* and encounter the similar problem below.

```
[ INFO ] Creating Inference Engine
[ INFO ] Reading the network: C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\Segmentation-COVID-19-master\Sample_Testing\model.xml
[ INFO ] Configuring input and output blobs
[ INFO ] Loading the model to the plugin
[ INFO ] Starting inference in asynchronous mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\inference_engine\samples\python\classification_sample_async\classification_sample_async.py", line 168, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.689\inference_engine\samples\python\classification_sample_async\classification_sample_async.py", line 111, in main
    exec_net.requests[i].async_infer({input_blob: input_data[i]})
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 1222, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.InferRequest.async_infer
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 1224, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.InferRequest.async_infer
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 1363, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.InferRequest._fill_inputs
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3,512,512) into shape (1,1,512,512)
```

Both messages can be found that the demo codes aren't supported grayscale images.

But how can I deal with the grayscale CT slices segmentation correctly?

I have also refered to *210-ct-scan-live-inference.ipynb* and *110-ct-segmentation-quantize.ipynb* in [openvino_notebooks](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks) on GitHub but in vain.

(My environment is Windows 11 with openvino_2021.4.689 version.)

Update with new testing result.

I have developed an easy inference code below.

```
from openvino.inference_engine import IECore, Blob, TensorDesc
import cv2
import numpy as np

IMG_PATH = "20.jpg"
XML_PATH = "model.xml"
BIN_PATH = "model.bin"

ie_core_handler = IECore()
network = ie_core_handler.read_network(model=XML_PATH, weights=BIN_PATH)
input_blob_name = next(iter(network.input_info))
network.input_info[input_blob_name].precision = 'FP16'
executable_network = ie_core_handler.load_network(network, device_name='MYRIAD', num_requests=1)
inference_request = executable_network.requests[0]

image = cv2.imread(IMG_PATH)
re_img = cv2.resize(src=image, dsize=(512, 512))
input_data = np.expand_dims(np.transpose(re_img, (2, 0, 1)), 0).astype(np.float16)
tensor_description = TensorDesc(precision="FP16", dims=(1, 1, 512, 512), layout='NCHW')
input_blob = Blob(tensor_description, input_data)

input_blob_name = next(iter(inference_request.input_blobs))
inference_request.set_blob(blob_name=input_blob_name, blob=input_blob)
inference_request.infer()
output_blob_name = next(iter(inference_request.output_blobs))
output = inference_request.output_blobs[output_blob_name].buffer
print(output)
```

It is workable with my other 3 channels projects.

But the error comes out with this 1 channel model.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\seg_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    input_blob = Blob(tensor_description, input_data)
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 214, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.Blob.__cinit__
AttributeError: Number of elements in provided numpy array 786432 and required by TensorDesc 262144 are not equal
```

So it means OpenVINO cannot support grayscale model whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can't expect any demo can still to work after replacing the model  with your own model, because different model has different requirement on input  format layout and pre/postprocessing.

For this AnamNet, I first export the model to onnx format by adding following line to https://github.com/NaveenPaluru/Segmentation-COVID-19/blob/master/Sample%20Testing/sample_test.ipynb (may be you must ensure the model is on CPU rather than GPU, I'm not very sure):

```py
torch.onnx.export(net, (inp1, ), 'model.onnx')
```

and then I load it into openvino and run inference (sampledata.mat is from https://github.com/NaveenPaluru/Segmentation-COVID-19/):

```py
import scipy.io as io
import openvino.runtime as ov
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

core = ov.Core()
model = core.read_model('model.onnx')

device = 'CPU'
model_cpu = core.compile_model(model, device)
k0 = model_cpu.output(0)

data = io.loadmat('sampledata.mat')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(50, 50))
for i, name in enumerate(['im1','im2','im3','im4']):
    inp = data[name]
    inp = np.reshape(inp,(512,512,1))
    inp = transforms.ToTensor()(inp).unsqueeze(dim=0)
    out = model_cpu.infer_new_request([inp])[k0]
    axs[i].imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

It reproduced similar result to what I saw in
https://github.com/NaveenPaluru/Segmentation-COVID-19/blob/master/Sample%20Testing/sample_test.ipynb

As for why your code (which is OpennVINO API 1.0 based) doesn't work, from the error log you show:

```
AttributeError: Number of elements in provided numpy array 786432 and required by TensorDesc 262144 are not equal
```

I guess OpenCV still produced 3-channel since 786432=512x512x3, and the model only accept 262144=512x512 input, thus you may follow the instructions described in [this link](https://dev-akash.github.io/posts/how-to-convert-color-image-to-grayscale-in-opencv-with-python.html) to ensure grayscale array is generated before feeding into OpenVINO.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it can work with your inference code.

Comment: But by the way, API2.0 seems to have some bug with NCS2. If I use `device = 'MYRIAD'`, it cannot work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Open Model Zoo demos and samples (segmentation_demo.py, classification_sample_async.py) only support 3 input channels, which is in BGR channels order.

1 input channel for Open Model Zoo demos and models might be supported and enabled in future release.

Comment: Stay tuned for Release Notes for new features enablement and model supports.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/openvino-relnotes.html

Comment: It means OpenVINO cannot support grayscale model whatever? I have updated other testing result at the end of the post, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If the model are trained for 3-channel RGB/BGR input, then you need to feed 3-channel content into the model.

Have you just tried to convert the 1-channel-input into 3-channel-input, i.e. convert the "pure grayscale image" into a colored image ("mycolor=cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)")? or using e.g. NUMPY to add additional channels/dimensions?

Would you have "enough" of those grayscale images to just retrain a model?

You might want to have a look into the still open Pull/MergeRequest "https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/training_extensions/pull/546" for breast ultrasound (simulation) training.